# Colocar uma imagem ao lado da outra no Stackoverflow

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de colocar 3 screenshots, uma do lado da outra no Stackoverflow, como mostra abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas respostas sempre tenho que tirar screnshot e ficar fazendo montagem com o Paint. Tem alguma forma de inserir pelo menos 3 imagens sendo um do lado da outra? Se caso não tenha, teria como redimensionar para não ficar grande sem mesmo depois de submete-las?

Comment: @diegofm Você é o flash, é muito rápido. Calma cara! =) Qndo eu cliquei apagar, você já tinha inserido o comentário. hehehe Obrigado pelo aviso.

Comment: Imagino que não seja possivel, uma vez que o site adiciona uma abaixo da outra, talvez pra evitar estouro do layout. Mas também nunca tentei algo assim, talvez alguém dê alguma sugestão alternativa.

Comment: @diegofm facilitaria para mim, para também ajudar as pessoas. Querendo ou não acabo gastando um tempo tendo que ficar fazendo montagem etc.

Comment: No Stackoverflow documentation tem tabelas, isso ajudaria, mas infelizmente não implementaram isso nem no SOen e no SOpt

Comment: Eu particulamente venho fazendo bastante o uso de gifs para demonstrar funcionamento, Se você olhar em algumas respostas recentes minhas(como [esta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145536/28595)), verá alguns gifs demonstrando a execução de algum código. Talvez fique até mais dinamico do que colocar varias imagens.

Comment: @diegofm bacana usar gif também, mas acaba também tomando um tempo para criação, a não ser tenha uma boa ferramenta para fazer isso.

Comment: Não sei se pode ajudar no seu caso, mas eu utilizo um programa chamado screenToGif2, e ele simplesmente grava a tela e converte para gif. Dá uma olhada se ele te ajuda de alguma forma,.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se a largura das imagens for pequena o suficiente, cabe mais de uma lado a lado.
Tanto usando HTML:

```
<img src="...">
<img src="...">
```

Quanto markdown:

```
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
```

[image]
[image]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Usando o `HTML` é possível usar as propriedades `height` e `width` da tag `img`?

Comment: Sim, pode usar os atributos

Comment: Engraçado, eu tentei usar o height e width na imagem, mas não funcionou. Vou tentar novamente!

Comment: @Randrade tentei editar usando essas propriedades, mas não funcionou.