# Existem duas diferentes formas de citar uma imagem?

Tags: suporte, markdown

> Imagem extraída [daqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5291/64969)

Eu vi que, quando pedimos para a imagem ser inserida pelos botões de formatação, o *markdown* fica mais ou menos assim:

```
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
```

Note:

1. Colchetes englobando...

   1. O `bang` !
   2. Descrição da imagem [entre colchetes]
   3. O link (que pode ser `[link com colchetes]` ou `(https://link.embarcado.com.parênteses)`)
2. O mesmo link anterior (que também pode ser `[link com colchetes]` ou `(https://link.embarcado.com.parênteses)`)

Então obtemos o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou usando a notação de links com parênteses:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, a própria página de ajuda indica para se referir a imagens assim:

```
![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]
```

Cuja estrutura é:

1. O `bang` !
2. Descrição da imagem [entre colchetes]
3. O link (que pode ser `[link com colchetes]` ou `(https://link.embarcado.com.parênteses)`)

Então obtemos o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou usando a notação de links com parênteses:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber:

1. Tem diferenças entre esses dois métodos? O do [colchete englobando tudo] e do bang ![colchetes](link)?
2. Se sim, qual o caso de uso desejado para cada um?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o que acontece!

Estava postando uma imagem e resolvi fazer um experimento: e se eu mudar um dos links? Fiz assim:

```
[![teste][img]][link]
```

E este é o resultado:

[image: teste]

O que aconteceu aqui? Na minha interpretação, uma imagem segue a seguinte estrutura sintática no MD aqui do SO:

```
<IMAGEM> ::= <BANG> <LINK>
<BANG> ::= '!'
<LINK> ::= <LINK-INLINE> | <LINK-IDX>
<LINK-INLINE> ::= '[' <TEXTO> '](' <URL> ')'
<LINK-IDX> ::= '[' <TEXTO> '][' <TEXTO> ']'
<IDX> ::= '  [' <TEXTO> ']: ' <URL>
```

Então, a derivação de `![teste][img]` é:

```
<IMAGEM>
'!' <LINK>
'!' <LINK-IDX>
'!' '[' <TEXTO> '][' <TEXTO> ']'
'![' 'teste' '][' <TEXTO> ']'
'![teste][' 'img' ']'
'![teste][img]'
```

Mas e a estrutura de `[![teste][img]][link]`? Nela nós temos um link e, no lugar do `<TEXTO>` do link, temos uma `<IMAGEM>`:

```
<LINK>
<LINK-IDX>
'[' <IMAGEM> '][' <TEXTO> ']'
'[' '![teste][img]' '][' <TEXTO> ']'
'[![teste][img]][' 'link' ']'
'[![teste][img]][link]'
```

Então, o primeiro padrão (o com os colchetes englobando) que eu pus na pergunta permite que eu coloque um link para um lugar arbitrário eu clicar na imagem. Por exemplo se você clicar na imagem acima você irá para o local do chat em que foi criado o texto do print.

O segundo padrão, entretanto, não permite que você faça essa brincadeira de ir para um lugar arbitrário ao clicar.

Answer (score 2):

Antigamente só tinha:

```
![descrição][numero dos links indexados]
```

E

```
![descrição](link da imagem)
```

Claro que você poderia fazer manualmente isto:

```
[![descrição][1]][1]
```

No entanto vou explicar o que presumo ser o motivo, muitas imagens excedem o limite de largura da postagem, sendo assim ao olhar o CSS notará isto:

```
.post-text img, .wmd-preview img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

O `max-width: 100%` limita para a largura da postagem, se a imagem for maior ela será reduzida, o que as vezes pode não ser fácil de visualizar, sendo assim este é o motivo do link, você clicará e será redirecionado podendo assim visualizar a imagem com as opções do navegador (geralmente a lupa e o scroll).

> **Nota:** criei um add-on que tem visualizador de imagens para o site [Extensão para Chrome, Opera e Firefox](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4075/3635)
>
> Desta maneira não será redirecionado e poderá se manter na postagem

Comment: Ao inspecionar elementos, ambos apontam para o mesmo CSS aqui no Firefox 56... Esse aqui `.post-text img, .wmd-preview img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}`